# "Something Else" Reference

Tags: usage, anaphora

I have a question about an implicit reference situation with "*else*":

> I wanted to see Mike, but he was busy with ***something else***.

"*Something else*" must be relative to another matter, but that matter is not explicitly referred to in the sentence.  So, is the sentence poorly written?

Comment: Nothing wrong.  _Something else_ is relative to my seeing him.

Comment: I think it should be "He was busy with something".

Comment: The **else** is referring to you meeting Mike. He cannot because he is busy with a different matter, *something else*. "Something else" is essentially a phrase for "another thing" or other ways of formatting a thing not the one in question. For example, if you get a feeling someone is leaving something out of what they just told you, you could ask them, "is there something else?"

Comment: @WilliamKappler: I suggest you change your comment to an answer, as this is a good answer to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is not poorly written because the context will provide the meaning for that "something else".

i.e.,

If the speaker doesn't know that "something else", then stressing "something else" means that there is curiosity.

If the speaker knows, then there might be disappointment or any other emotion relative to the speaker's outlook/attitude/character.

All in the context.